# The limit of a sequence of uniformly bounded linearly operators is bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

Let, $(X, ||\cdot||_{X}) $ and $(Y,||\cdot||_{Y})$ be two normed vector spaces. Let,
$\{T_{n} \}_{n \ge 1} $ be a sequence of linearly bounded operators; as in, we let $M >0$, then $||T_n(x)||_{\infty} < M, \forall x \in X, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$
We also have that,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} T_n(x) = T(x), ~ ~ \forall x \in X.$$
We wish to now prove that:
$$||T||_{\infty} < M.$$

Let, $x \in X$. We have that,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ||T_n(x) - T(x)||_{Y} = 0 \implies \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |~ ~  ||T_n(x)||_{Y} - ||T(x)||_{Y}~ |  = 0.$$
Observe that,
$$\frac{||T_n(x)||_{Y}}{||x||_{X}} < M.$$
Then we take the limit of both sides and obtain:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{||T_n(x)||_{Y}}{||x||_{X}} < \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} M \implies \frac{||T(x)||_{Y}}{||x||_{X}} < M .$$
Hence,
$$||T||_{\infty} < M. $$

Any mistakes in this proof? Thanks.

Comment: as in ... what ??

Comment: This is a corollary of the uniform boundedness principle. $X$ must be assumed to be complete, or else the claim fails.

Comment: I think you don't need to assume $\| T_n(x)\| < \infty$ since you assume that $\forall x \in X, \lim_{n \to \infty} T_n(x) = T(x) \in Y$, right ?

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. can you tell me where my proof fails if I do not assume completeness? Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that $M$ depends on the choice of $x$. You must prove that $||Tx||\le c ||x||$ for all $x$, where $c$ does not depend on $x$. This is where the uniform boundedness principle is used.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. I apologize, maybe I was not clear, I have now fixed the statement, the constant we can say that the sequence is uniformly bounded.

Comment: @Physor done, thanks.

Comment: I still don't understand your "as in", perhaps my english is not that good

Comment: @Physor So, just to be clear: You mean that $\sup_n \sup_x ||T_nx||$ is finite? That is, $(T_n)$ is uniformly bounded (bounded in the operator norm)? If yes, then your proof is correct. If the sequence is only assumed to be pointwise bounded, that is, for every $x$ there exists $M=M(x)$ such that $\sup_n ||T_nx||< M$, then the claim holds if and only if $X$ is complete (different proof).

Comment: Interesting @EvangelopoulosF., I never knew that to be true, I will look into that proof. Thanks.

Comment: you write "for every $x$ there is $M$ .." that implies ($\forall x, \sup_n \|T_n(x)\| < \infty$), call it $(*)$, well this $(*)$ is implied by your last assumption $\forall x \in X, \lim_{n \to \infty} T_n(x) = T(x) \in Y$. And the $(*)$ is actually one condition to use the uniform boundedness principle

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. I didn't write any proof, I wanted to point out that the last assumption in the statement above is implied by the one before it. So I'd guess that it is not very good statement of a theorem, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Physor, this was a homework question that I'm reviewing, but I'm not so sure if convergence implies uniform bounds of the functions in the sequence?

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF.: here OP is assuming uniform boudnedness right off the bat, so there is no need for Banach-Steinhaus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is fine, but it is unnecessarily convoluted.

The key fact is that the norm is continuous; concretely, as you implicitly mention,
$$
\big|\,\|Tx\|-\|T_nx\|\,\big|\leq \|Tx-T_nx\|.
$$
From this is follows directly that
$$
\|Tx\|=\lim_n\|T_nx\|.
$$
Now your result is just the fact that a limit of a sequence real numbers is bounded by any bound of the sequence. Explicitly, for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $n$ such that
$$
\|Tx\|\leq\|T_nx\|+\varepsilon<M+\varepsilon. 
$$
As this can be done for all $\varepsilon>0$,
$$
\|Tx\|\leq M. 
$$